# Additional join condition in Objection.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mariadb, objection.js

I'm writing the following sort of query using Objection.js Node.js ORM:

```js
return Account.query()
    .alias('accounts')
    .whereIn('accounts.ID', accountIds)
    .where('accounts.DELETE_FLAG', 'N')
    .where('accounts.ISDELETED', false)
    .withGraphJoined('contacts')
    .where('contacts.DELETE_FLAG', 'N')
    .where('contacts.ISDELETED', false)
    .execute();
```

currently this is generating a query like:

```sql
select accounts.*, contacts.* from accounts
left join contacts on (accounts.ID = contacts.ACCOUNTID)
where accounts.ID in (...)
    and contacts.DELETE_FLAG = 'N'
    and contacts.ISDELETED = false
```

Instead of the two `contacts` conditions being added to the query as part of the normal where clause, I need it to be added to the join condition like:

```sql
select accounts.*, contacts.* from accounts
left join contacts on (accounts.ID = contacts.ACCOUNTID)
    and (contacts.DELETE_FLAG = 'N')
    and (contacts.ISDELETED = false)
where accounts.ID in (...)
```

I'm having trouble finding how to do this in the documentation. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the difference in those queries? Doesn't query planner optimize them to be the same?

Comment: At the time I was running into a difference, but I forgot to include it in the question and I forget what the problem was now. According to  https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/difference-between-where-and-on-in-sql/ it appears there is a slight difference, but it sounds like I should be leaning towards the syntax that Knex is creating here instead of trying to add conditions to the join clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `modifyGraph`, the query will be a little different in the sense that it will not add filters to the left join but will use a sub-select as join. Nonetheless the result will be the same as filtering in join with the plus of maintaining the graph feature:

```
return Account.query()
.alias('accounts')
.whereIn('accounts.ID', accountIds)
.where('accounts.DELETE_FLAG', 'N')
.where('accounts.ISDELETED', false)
.withGraphJoined('contacts')
.modifyGraph('contacts', , builder => {
    builder.where('DELETE_FLAG', 'N')
           .where('ISDELETED', false)
 )

.execute();
```

Comment: filtering with subqueries has a limit: one can filter a subquery using other JOINed tables. That's how SQL works. So even though in many cases it is possible to get the result using "subqueries", there are a lot of cases when you really need to use an addition `ON` condition with references to one of the already joined tables.